# Background Worker or best approach for locked thread

Tags: backgroundworker

We are using VB.net 2015. When the application loads it will check for the model file to be present and then load that file for processing. IE

```
If frmMain.chkTMQEnableHortizontalScaling.Checked Then

ShapeModel = TMTrainImage.CreateAnisoShapeModel(4, -10 / Rad, 20 / Rad, "auto", RScaleMin, RScaleMax, "auto", ScaleMin,CScaleMax, "auto", "none", "use_polarity", "auto", "auto")

Else

ShapeModel = TMTrainImage.CreateScaledShapeModel(4, -10 / Rad, 20 / ad, "auto", 1, 1, "auto", "none", "use_polarity", "auto", "auto")

End If
```

The Problem is sometimes that model will become corrupted and it will lock the gui and stay there indeffinatly. so I decided to make a background on the main form and address it as such.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, err As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker.DoWork

    BackgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True

    If BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending Then
        err.Cancel = True
    End If

    If chkTMQEnableHortizontalScaling.Checked Then
        ShapeModel = TMTrainImage.CreateAnisoShapeModel(4, -10 / Rad, 20 / Rad, "auto", RScaleMin, RScaleMax, "auto", CScaleMin, CScaleMax, "auto", "none", "use_polarity", "auto", "auto")
    Else
        ShapeModel = TMTrainImage.CreateScaledShapeModel(4, -10 / Rad, 20 / Rad, "auto", 1, 1, "auto", "none", "use_polarity", "auto", "auto")
    End If
    PartLoadSuccess = True
```

and it is called in main loop

```
Dim tmPath As String
            Dim tmString
            Dim timeoutCount As Integer
            Dim timeoutValue As Integer = 5
            tmPath = CurrentFilePath & "Image1.Tiff"
            frmMain.BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()   'start worker frmmain.backgroundworker.dowork
            Do While frmMain.BackgroundWorker.IsBusy And Not timeout
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
                timeoutCount += 1   ' increment timeout value
                If PartLoadSuccess = True Then Exit Do
                If timeoutCount = timeoutValue Then
                    timeout = True ' connection timed out
                    frmMain.BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()
                    frmMain.BackgroundWorker.Dispose()
                    frmMain.lblAlarmMessage.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                    frmMain.lblAlarmMessage.Text = "()" & vbCr & "Timeout Loading  Image" & vbCr & Err.Description
                    If File.Exists(tmPath) Then
                        tmString = "Image " & Date.Now & ".tiff"
                        tmString = Replace(tmString, "/", "-")
                        tmString = Replace(tmString, ":", "-")
                        File.Move(tmPath, CurrentFilePath & tmString)
                        File.Copy(ConfigPath & "Default.tiff", CurrentFilePath & "Image.tiff")
                    End If
                    'timeout = False    ' connection timed out
                    PartLoad = False
                    LoadImage()
                    'Exit Sub
                End If
            Loop
            timeout = False

            Do While frmMain.BackgroundWorker.IsBusy And Not timeout
                Thread.Sleep(1000)
                timeoutCount += 1   ' increment timeout value
                If PartLoadSuccess = True Then Exit Do
                If timeoutCount = timeoutValue Then
                    frmMain.BackgroundWorker.CancelAsync()
                    frmMain.BackgroundWorker.Dispose()
                End If
            Loop
```

If the worker takes more then 5 seconds I want to kill that thread then remove the current model copy a "generic" one in place and let the program continue.

I am able to make it through first iteration fine but the worker is not stopping and I am unable to run it again.

I am sure I did not describe this all to well but appreciate any support criticisms or whatever that I may receive.

Comment: You seem to be starting the BackgroundWorker but then blocking the UI thread anyhow waiting for the BackgroundWorker to complete.

Comment: the program cant go forward without a valid model I assumed I was starting the backgroundworker. and the main thread would loop for 5 seconds and if no partloadsuccess from backgroundworker then I would know it is locked up so I could remove that model file,throw in the generic and re run the worker.

Comment: It would be better to disable the UI `frmMain.Enabled = false` while ensuring you have a valid model, then set Enabled to true once the model is available. That would allow the UI thread to keep pumping the message queue.